# Is my Flask login safe?

Tags: python, security, session, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've made the following Login in Flask. Now I'm wondering if it is secure. If not what do I have to add to enhance seurity. I know stuff like SSL is important too but for now I'm only interested in what I can do to make my Flask code safer.

```
#Login
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user:
            if bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
                login_user(user)
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

        return render_template('login.html', form=form, ermsg="Invalid credentials")

    return render_template('login.html', form=form)

#Sign up
@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    form = RegisterForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        pw_hash = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data, 12)
        new_user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=pw_hash)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()

        return render_template('login.html', form=form, sumsg="User created!")

    return render_template('signup.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 1):

the login process seems secure.

But you didn't check the potential existing user in the signup form, or existing email address. Unless this is managed by the underlying `User` schema.

And you should require a minimal password complexity. Danjgo does this by default but the `passwordmeter` package could help you to achieve this.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/passwordmeter

Comment: Thank you. Is my session safe too? Do I need to add user_datastore which is part of flask_security to protect my session?

Comment: Yes, it's a good practice to use well known and documented essential add-ons like Flask-Security rather than re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

- It is vulnerable to [account enumeration via timing attacks](https://littlemaninmyhead.wordpress.com/2015/07/26/account-enumeration-via-timing-attacks/) because you only do the bcrypt when the username exists.  You can fix it by adding a dummy computation when the user does not exist.  Not a major issue, but you should at least be aware of it.
- Although you did well in choosing bcrypt, I agree with @glenfant that at least something should be done with password complexity.  However, recommend having a read on [NIST's new password guidelines](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/08/18/nists-new-password-rules-what-you-need-to-know/).  Don't follow traditional guidelines that annoy users.